# cp: cannot stat `shtool': No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, debian

on my web server, I need to use ssh2. I've tried to install libssh2-1, libssh2-1-dev and libssh2-php, and after to restart Apache2 nothing change, I've the same error when I whant to use the ssh2_connect function.

In order to resolve my problem, I've tried to install ssh2 with PECL (from this tutorial: http://lindev.fr/?post/2009/01/19/Installer-le-module-SSH2-pour-php) , but when I launch this commande:

> phpize && ./configure --with-ssh2 && make

I've got this error:

> PHP Api Version:         20090626
>   Zend Module Api No:      20090626
>   Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
>   cp: cannot stat `shtool': No such file or directory
>   chmod: cannot access`/usr/local/src/ssh2-0.11.0/build/shtool': No such file or directory
>   shtool at '/usr/local/src/ssh2-0.11.0/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable. 
>   Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.

For information, I use PHP5.3.
How to fix my problem ?

Comment: does the file `/usr/local/src/ssh2-0.11.0/build/shtool` exist? if it does, is it executable?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). If you need the libssh2 functions to support legacy code that uses them you can use this:

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer

That'll emulate the libssh2 functions with phpseclib.